# Simple, how to log (with logcat) a query?

Tags: java, android, database, logcat

I have this code in eclipse, I'm trying to output all the data from the database table out into a log. How would I log this?

```
    //---retrieves a particular contact---
public Cursor getTrailer(long rowId) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_RATING}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

Comment: Simply by `Log.d("TAG_NAME", "YOUR_QUERY_OUTPUT");` or did I miss your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move into all rows in the cursor.
you can try this:

```
mCursor.moveToFirst();
do {
      //print all your columns:
      Log.d("Your class or activity","ID: +"mCursor.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ID"),"ETC:"+mCursor.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ETC"));

   } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
```